# CSS3 calc() validation: Value Error : width Parse Error

Tags: css, w3c-validation, css-calc

I need to validate a CSS3 file where I'm using the following code:

```
width:calc(96.3% - 312px)
```

It returns this error:

> Value Error : width Parse Error - 312px)

My last choice is to use a Javascript function on page load and window resize to get the width value when it's possible using CSS3 (only for IE8 or older).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the validator. Your `calc()` syntax is valid. Don't worry about it.

Whenever you need to validate your CSS, remove just that declaration so it does not cause irrecoverable parse errors.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. Now I found the bug: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=18913. Is there a method to hide/remove a declaration without editing the code? Thanks.

Comment: @Gerard: I don't think so.

Comment: unfortunately this bug is still there almost two years later - I just found this question&answer here after having the same problem validating and googling for it...